# MVC4: How to force browser's default download dialog when using Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC4: goal: when user clicks link : create CSV-file type of data in memory and present user with browser's default download dialog to allow user to save as CSV file on his system.
When using code below: browser's default download dialog does Not display (tested in Chrome and IE). Visually nothing happens as result of user's click on the link.
How to force browser's default download dialog in this case ?

MyView.cshtml

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_MyTableView", Model)
</div>


@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function downloadMyCSV() {
                alert("start download");  // pops-up

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("DownLoadMyCSV", "Home", new { Area ="MyArea" })",
                    data: {}, 
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (data) { 
                        alert(data);   // shows data as commadelimited string                         

                    }

                });
         }


    </script>

}
```

_MyTableView.cshtml

```
    <a href="#" id="btnDowloadCsv" onclick="downloadMyCSV()">Download my CSV</a>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public FileContentResult DownLoadMyCSV()
    {
        string csv = "John, Steven, Smith";
        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "myreport123.csv");
    }
```

How to force browser's default download dialog in this case ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are only 2 ways that we have gotten the csv to fire.  first was a postback which redirects to the csv download but that isn't ideal.  the second way is a link with a blank target.  something like this

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" target="_blank">Download Links(csv)</a>
```

a new page won't open but the download dialog will be fired.  Everything else we attempted would call the method on the controller but the download dialog never showed on the ui.  Hope this helps

Comment: Many thanks Matt for the quick, correct and to the point answer. The following works: _MyTableView.cshtml : <a href="@Url.Action("DownLoadMyCSV", "Home", new { Area = "MyArea" })" target="_blank">Download my CSV</a>. And I do Not need downloadMyCSV() in MyView.cshtml anymore. I Do get browser's default download dialog in IE and Chrome now. I will mmark this as an answer. Thanks again